# Java GridLayout: south-JPanel covers center-JPanel?

Tags: java, resize, grid-layout, blackjack

I'm currently working on my first real blackJack program. It's nearly finished, but i've ran into a major problem.

When I run the code, it displays the players card in the center JPanel, as planned. But once I'm done and press to end the turn, only the dealers cards are displayed, rather than both. Before resizing my cardImages to make them smaller, they would appear as tall, narrow  strips (only a strip in the middle of the card would be shown, not the whole thing), covering the whole screen from top to bottom.

I believe that once I end the turn and thus cardsImages are added to the south JPanel, it minimizes the center JPanel (presumingly because the components are so tall) and ends up taking up all the space instead. Although I'm not sure this is the case, its just a guess.

Even avter I made the images smaller, although the whole card now appears, the dealers cards are still replacing the player cards on the screen. So I'm assuming I need to resize the actual space assigned for the images somehow?

Searching through stackoverflow leads me to believe that I need to use gridbaglayout and resize the actual space for the cards, but I can't seem to find any threads describing how such resizing could actually be done, even though i've struggled pretty much all day and yesterday with this problem.

So yeah, any help or insights would be very much appreciated! Thanks beforehand.

If you want to use the cards I made two zip files; One with the big cards and one with the resized cards:

Original size (big): 
http://www.filedropper.com/cardsoriginalsizebigzip

Resized:
http://www.filedropper.com/cardsresizedsmallzip

My Code:
(Keep in mind it's not quite done and I still need to fix the restart game button and add some info, error handling etc., so don't worry about that. Also this is my first semester and my teacher hasn't helped me at all with this so my programming style is probably really shitty, but please bear with me as I try my best.)

```js
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random.*;

public class BlackJack
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Interface Win = new Interface ();
 }

 public static int value(int cardID)
 //stores values for each "card ID number" 
 {

  int [] cardValue = {2, 2, 2, 2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};
  
  return cardValue[cardID];
 }
}

class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 
 int index;
 int IDIndex = 0;

 // Add all image components here:
 ImageIcon [] cardImage = new ImageIcon[52];
 {
 for (index = 0; index <= 51; index++)
  cardImage[index] = new ImageIcon(index + ".png");
 }
 ImageIcon Empty = new ImageIcon("blank");
 
 //identify variables
 int cardCounter = 0;
 int dealerCardCounter = 0;
 int cardID;
 boolean Continue;
 
 //keeps track of cards left in the deck. 
 boolean [] cardsLeft = new boolean [52];{
 for (index = 0; index < cardsLeft.length; index++)
  cardsLeft[index] = true;
 }
  
 // Interface components here:
 int plyrSum = 0;
 int dealerSum = 0;
 int aceCounter = 0;
 JLabel Info = new JLabel (""); //<== this will be (setText to) either "Bust!", "Black Jack!"/"21!" or "What would you like to do?"
 JLabel PlyrCardSum = new JLabel("Sum: " + plyrSum);
 JLabel DealerCardSum = new JLabel("Dealer sum: " + dealerSum);
 JLabel winLoseLabel = new JLabel("");
 
 JLabel [] cardLabel = new JLabel[20];
 {
  for (index = 0; index < 20; index ++)
   cardLabel[index] = new JLabel (Empty);
 }
 
 JButton hit = new JButton ("Hit!");
 JButton stay = new JButton ("Stay");
 JButton reset = new JButton ("New Round");
 
 //JPanels here:
 JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,15));
 JPanel plyrCards = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,15));
 JPanel dealerCards = new JPanel (new GridLayout(1,2,5,15));
  
 public Interface ()
 {
  
  super ("BlackJack 21");
  setSize (1367,729);
  setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible (true);
    
  //GridBagConstraints card = new GridBagConstraints();
  
  Container contentArea = getContentPane();
  contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
  
  //Event listeners
  hit.addActionListener (this);
  stay.addActionListener (this);
  reset.addActionListener (this); 
  
  //add panels to different compass points on the content area
  contentArea.add("North",buttons);
  contentArea.add("Center",plyrCards);
  contentArea.add("South",dealerCards);
  
  //Add components to panels
  buttons.add(hit);
  buttons.add(stay);
  buttons.add(reset);
  buttons.add(PlyrCardSum);
  
  for (index = 0; index < 10; index ++)
   plyrCards.add(cardLabel[index]);
  for (index = 10; index < 20; index ++)
   dealerCards.add(cardLabel[index]);
  
 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
 {
  
  if (event.getSource() == hit)
  {
   if (plyrSum < 21)
   {
    Continue = true;
    while (Continue == true) //Generates a new random number if that number has already been generated
    {
     cardID = (int) RandomNumber.GetRandomNumber(51); 
     if (cardsLeft[cardID] == true) //If a new card is drawn, continue normally
     {
      cardCounter++;
      cardsLeft[cardID] = false; //save that the card was drawn
      plyrSum += BlackJack.value(cardID); //add value to sum
      cardLabel[IDIndex].setIcon(cardImage[cardID]); //Display card
      PlyrCardSum.setText("Sum: " + plyrSum);
      IDIndex++;
      if(cardID >= 47)
       aceCounter++;
      Continue = false; //Stop the loop that draws a new card
      
     }
     
    }
    
   }
     
   if (plyrSum > 21 && aceCounter > 0) //If bust, reduce values of ace by 10 (from 11 to 1). 
   {

     plyrSum -= 10;
     aceCounter--;
   
   }
   
  }
  
  //Stay/Finish round button
  if (event.getSource() == stay)
  {
   
   aceCounter = 0;
   cardCounter = 10; //Starts at 10 so it will end up in the south JPanel
   while (dealerSum < 17)
   {
    cardID = (int) RandomNumber.GetRandomNumber(52);
    if (cardsLeft [cardID] == true)
    {
     dealerSum += BlackJack.value(cardID);
     cardsLeft [cardID] = false;
     cardLabel[cardCounter].setIcon(cardImage[cardID]); //Display card
     if(cardID >= 47)
      aceCounter++;
     cardCounter++;

     
     if (plyrSum > 21 && aceCounter > 0) //If bust, reduce values of ace by 10 (from 11 to 1). 
     {
     
      dealerSum -= 10; 
      aceCounter--;
      
     }
     
    }
          
   }
    
  }
  
  //Reset button
  if (event.getSource() == reset)
  {
   
   for (index = 0; index < 52; index++)
   {
    cardsLeft[index] = true;
   }
   
   cardCounter = 0;
   
  }
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, try this one out, I altered it for the images in a gridbaglayout

```
public class BlackJack
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Interface Win = new Interface ();
    }

    public static int value(int cardID)
    //stores values for each "card ID number" 
    {

        int [] cardValue = {2, 2, 2, 2, 
                3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
                9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
                10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
                10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11};

        return cardValue[cardID];
    }
}

class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    int index;
    int IDIndex = 0;

    // Add all image components here:
    ImageIcon [] cardImage = new ImageIcon[52];
    {
    for (index = 0; index <= 51; index++)
        cardImage[index] = new ImageIcon(index + ".png");

    }
    ImageIcon Empty = new ImageIcon("blank");

    //identify variables
    int cardCounter = 0;
    int dealerCardCounter = 0;
    int cardID;
    boolean Continue;

    //keeps track of cards left in the deck. 
    boolean [] cardsLeft = new boolean [52];{
    for (index = 0; index < cardsLeft.length; index++)
        cardsLeft[index] = true;
    }

    // Interface components here:
    int plyrSum = 0;
    int dealerSum = 0;
    int aceCounter = 0;
    JLabel Info = new JLabel (""); //<== this will be (setText to) either "Bust!", "Black Jack!"/"21!" or "What would you like to do?"
    JLabel PlyrCardSum = new JLabel("Sum: " + plyrSum);
    JLabel DealerCardSum = new JLabel("Dealer sum: " + dealerSum);
    JLabel winLoseLabel = new JLabel("");

    JLabel [] cardLabel = new JLabel[20];
    {
        for (index = 0; index < 20; index ++){
            cardLabel[index] = new JLabel (Empty);
        cardLabel[index].setSize(50, 50);
        }
    }

    JButton hit = new JButton ("Hit!");
    JButton stay = new JButton ("Stay");
    JButton reset = new JButton ("New Round");

    //JPanels here:
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JPanel plyrCards = new JPanel();
    JPanel dealerCards = new JPanel ();

    public Interface ()
    {

        super ("BlackJack 21");
        setSize (1000,729);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);

        //GridBagConstraints card = new GridBagConstraints();

        Container contentArea = getContentPane();
        contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);

        //Event listeners
        hit.addActionListener (this);
        stay.addActionListener (this);
        reset.addActionListener (this); 

        //add panels to different compass points on the content area
        GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        buttons.add(hit);
        buttons.add(stay);
        buttons.add(reset);
        buttons.add(PlyrCardSum);
        contentArea.setLayout(grid);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 4;


        contentArea.add(buttons,c);
        GridBagLayout grid1 = new GridBagLayout();
        plyrCards.setLayout(grid1);
        for (index = 0; index < 10; index ++){
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            c.gridx = index;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            plyrCards.add(cardLabel[index],c);
        }


        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 10;
        //plyrCards.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        contentArea.add(plyrCards,c);
        GridBagLayout grid2 = new GridBagLayout();
        dealerCards.setLayout(grid2);
        for (index = 10; index < 20; index ++){
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            c.gridx = index;
            c.gridy = 2;
            c.gridwidth = 1;
            dealerCards.add(cardLabel[index],c);
        }


        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 10;
        //plyrCards.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        contentArea.add(dealerCards,c);
        //contentArea.add(dealerCards,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Add components to panels





    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        if (event.getSource() == hit)
        {
            if (plyrSum < 21)
            {
                Continue = true;
                while (Continue == true) //Generates a new random number if that number has already been generated
                {
                    cardID = (int) RandomNumber.nextInt(51 + 1); 
                    if (cardsLeft[cardID] == true) //If a new card is drawn, continue normally
                    {
                        cardCounter++;
                        cardsLeft[cardID] = false; //save that the card was drawn
                        plyrSum += Testing.value(cardID); //add value to sum
                        Image resizedImage = cardImage[cardID].getImage();
                        resizedImage = resizedImage.getScaledInstance(100, 150, 1);
                    cardLabel[IDIndex].setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage)); //Display card
                        //cardLabel[IDIndex].setIcon(cardImage[cardID]); //Display card
                        PlyrCardSum.setText("Sum: " + plyrSum);
                        IDIndex++;
                        if(cardID >= 47)
                            aceCounter++;
                        Continue = false; //Stop the loop that draws a new card

                    }

                }

            }

            if (plyrSum > 21 && aceCounter > 0) //If bust, reduce values of ace by 10 (from 11 to 1). 
            {

                    plyrSum -= 10;
                    aceCounter--;

            }

        }

        //Stay/Finish round button
        if (event.getSource() == stay)
        {

            aceCounter = 0;
            cardCounter = 10; //Starts at 10 so it will end up in the south JPanel
            while (dealerSum < 17)
            {
                cardID = (int) RandomNumber.nextInt(52);
                if (cardsLeft [cardID] == true)
                {
                    dealerSum += Testing.value(cardID);
                    cardsLeft [cardID] = false;
                    Image resizedImage = cardImage[cardID].getImage();
                        resizedImage = resizedImage.getScaledInstance(100, 150,1);
                    cardLabel[cardCounter].setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage)); //Display card
                    if(cardID >= 47)
                        aceCounter++;
                    cardCounter++;


                    if (plyrSum > 21 && aceCounter > 0) //If bust, reduce values of ace by 10 (from 11 to 1). 
                    {

                        dealerSum -= 10;    
                        aceCounter--;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        //Reset button
        if (event.getSource() == reset)
        {

            for (index = 0; index < 52; index++)
            {
                cardsLeft[index] = true;
            }

            cardCounter = 0;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The cards actually show up now. Now all I have to do is fugure out what was different, and learn from it. Happy new year!